# Customizing MSI repair

Tags: windows-installer, repair

I'm using visual studio 2013 , I have an MSI installer that works fine , during the installation I'm installing another software - lets name it test sw- using command line , like this

```
Process process = Process.Start(Path, "/verysilent");
```

if I uninstall the test sw manually , how can I re-install it when I repair from the MSI for the main application ?

Comment: a custom action that runs on maintenance. isn't that how you are starting it now? Just make sure the execution condition of the custom action allows it to run on repair too. Condition example: Installed AND (NOT REMOVE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work by accident. VS setups have things called install custom actions where you don't get to define the condition for what that means. For files being installed the condition will most likely be something like $C__EC9EFAF2178F433499A4760BEE578FA6>2 meaning call the CA when the component is marked for install. You can open your MSI file with Orca, go to the InstallExecuteSequence table and see if the condition has that form. So just test it and see if it works as is.

In addition, you'll need to know exactly what the Path is, just in case your current code runs the setup from the install location which may not be available. Plus if it's an MSI-based setup it will fail anyway because you can't have recursive install operations, but if you've done the initial install ok it presumably isn't a problem.